# Cannot find the URL for a web app deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I just deployed the calculator.war file of a basic Calculator web app to the webapps directory of my Tomcat server but I can't access it when I go to my url. e.g. localhost/calculator

I use port 80 instead of 8080 for Tomcat.

This is the web.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

```
<display-name>Calculator Spring-WS Service</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the folder structure of my webapps folder:

calculator
  -META-INF
  -WEB-INF
  -calculator

Comment: Recommend adding mcuh more info, for instance the name of the class, web.xml mapping, full url, etc...

Comment: Afungus, post your source code, webapp's folder struture!

Comment: This is the folder structure: